# Bootstrap 3 and form css trick issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I came up with something, not terribly complex but nice.

You'll click a label, and up comes a textbox, save button, and cancel button. All in css. Not terribly complex, moving on.

The issue I have comes with Now that the css/html structure is working right after some tweaking, to make use of the bootstrap form classes.

Here if my form:

```
<form>
    <input id="toggle-username" type="checkbox" class="toggle-username">
    <input id="username-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-username">

    <label for="toggle-username" class="toggle-username">
        <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3> <!-- twig -->
    </label>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}" class="username form-control">            
        <label for="username-submit" class="input-group-addon submit-username glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></label>
        <label for="toggle-username" class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle toggle-username"></label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Then my sass:

```
label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
input {
    display: none;
}
input[type="text"] {
    display: none;
    ~ label {
        display: none;
    }
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    &:checked  {
        ~ .input-group {
            input, label {
                display: block !important;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My desired result:

[image]

And my actual result:

[image]

Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

Rather than setting the label to block, I used table-cell

```
label {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Pretty simple at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you. Need to add your other classes back in

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}" class="username form-control" /> 
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i></span>
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></span>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S3QZp/

Comment: It won't because I am using the label's to toggle checked states in a checkbox used to show or hide this form's elements. As well as submit it.

Comment: a label isn't meant to be used as a toggle. I'd try seeing if you can acheive it with buttons. you're not following the bootstrap docs for the labels so it's not going to work that way. Also not semantically correct

Comment: Can a button change the state of a form element?
I'm not going for semantics here. I was going for a cross browser no-js solution.

Comment: yes a button can be used to trigger the state of a form element. However, based on what you are trying to do, you might want to explore the .collapse class in bootstrap. See if you can attach that to your input so that on focus it reveals the buttons